# Photoshop brush dense in center and thin on the sides?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

When using a spaced scattering brush, which looks like many small dots, how can I make sure that the dots on the left and right sides are thin and keep the ones in the middle bigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't control sample size based on a distance for `Scatter`. I'd suggest to make a brush tip with a larger shape in the middle and smaller shapes around it to imitate this effect:

[image]